# issues with ngPattern directive

Tags: regex, validation, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've this code:

```
<form name="test">
    <input type="text" ng-model="code" name="code" ng-pattern="/^code_[0-9]+$/"/>
    <div ng-show="test.code.$dirty && test.code.$invalid">
        Error:
        <span ng-show="test.code.$error.pattern">Pattern fail.</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have 2 issues with this code:

1. Strings like "   code_232  ", "code_232  " "   code_232" pass the validation. I'm not expert with regex, so this could be an issue simply related to the regex i wrote: `/^code_[0-9]+$/`
2. If i start writing "code_23892" (a correct string), i get the error
   message while i'm still writing (`test.code.$error.pattern = true`). Is there a built-in way to avoid this? So my desidered behaviour is:

> If i write "cod", and the input has still focus: no error
>
> If i write "cod" and the input loses focus: error.
>
> If i write "a", "ca", "coa" etc.: error, cause the pattern is already violated.

**Is this already possible, or i've write a custome validation directive to achieve this?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason that whitespace doesn't trigger a failed validation is because ng-model automatically trims the value. If you don't want that, you can add `ng-trim="false"` to your `<input />`. Note that ng-trim is a quite new attribute, so you might have to update your Angular version.

About your second question; I don't think you can avoid the validation to run during the time you type, but you could change your code to only display the error when the input looses focus. I don't think that something like `ng-blur` and `ng-focus` exists, but it should be pretty simple to implement them.

Comment: i'm using AngularJS 1.0.5 (released today)... ng-trim="false" doesn't work

Comment: I think ng-trim is new in 1.1 which is still in unstable, unfortunately. EDIT: It's in the 1.1.1 changelog here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1.1.1

Comment: +1 Thanks for your help! I will wait more answers before accepting your answer.

Comment: Sure, anything in particular that you feel I didn't answer?

Comment: your answer is complete. i just waited to have more answers, but it seems it does not work. thanks again